# Regular expression to remove empty <span> tags

Tags: php, html, regex

I would like such empty span tags (filled with `&nbsp;` and space) to be removed:

`<span> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; </span>`

I've tried with this regex, but it needs adjusting:

`(<span>(&nbsp;|\s)*</span>)`

`preg_replace('#<span>(&nbsp;|\s)*</span>#si','<\\1>',$encoded);`

Comment: You'll need to URL decode the content of your span tags first before your regex will work on the sample you gave above.

Comment: Your regex is OK. Just change the replacement string from `'<\\1>'` to `''`.

Answer (score 5):

Translating Kent Fredric's regexp to PHP :

```
preg_match_all('#<span[^>]*(?:/>|>(?:\s|&nbsp;)*</span>)#im', $html, $result);
```

This will match :

- autoclosing spans
- spans on multilines and whatever the case
- spans with attributes
- span with unbreakable spaces

Maybe you should about including spans containings only `<br />` as well...

As usual, when it comes to tweak regexp, some tools are handy :

http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/

Comment: The OP wants the empty SPAN elements _removed_.

Answer (score 2):

.

```
qr{<span[^>]*(/>|>\s*?</span>)}
```

Should get the gist of them. ( Including XML style-self closing tags ie:  )

But you **really** shouldn't use regex for HTML processing.

**Answer only relevant to the context of the question that was visible before the formatting errors were corrected**

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't be stuffed with nasty quoting styles needed :/ user exercise to make the regex suited to their language :p

Comment: i'm really getting tired of people saying that you shouldn't use regexes on any sort of XML or HTML. Sometimes using something like Beautiful Soup *really isn't appropriate*.

Comment: In this case it would be fine, as long as it never occurs inside quoted areas. That makes this very brittle, and I wouldn't use it, except in a pinch.

Comment: @nickf: its to combat the problem of millions of novices whom use it as the first port of call and then XSS-exploit themself.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose these span are generated by some program, since they don't seem to have any attribute.
I am perplex why you need to put the space they enclose between angle brackets, but then again I don't know the final purpose of the code.
I think the solution is given by Kent: you have to make the match non-greedy: since you use dotall option (s), you will match everything between the first span and the last closing span!

So the answer should look like:

`preg_replace('#<span>(&nbsp;|\s)*?</span>#si', '<$1>', $encoded);`

(untested)

Answer (score 1):

> I've tried with this regex, but it needs adjusting:

In what way does the regex in the original question fail?

> The problem comes when the span gets
>   nested like: `<span><span> &nbsp; </span></span>`

This is an example of why using regexes to parse HTML doesn't work particularly well.  Depending on your regex flavor, this situation is either impossible to handle in a single pass or merely very difficult.  I don't know PHP's regex engine well enough to say which category it falls into, but, if the only problem is that it takes out the inner `<span>` and leaves the outer one alone, then you may want to consider simply re-running your substitution repeatedly until it runs out of things to do.

Comment: Yes, I agree but I wanted to know if there's a way to re-run it recursively? Otherwise it becomes difficult to predict the nested tags numbers/names...

Answer (score 0):

If your only issue are nested span tags, you can run the search-and-replace with the regex you have in a loop until the regex no longer finds any matches.

This may not be a very elegant solution, but it'll perform well enough.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to nesting tags problems, still not complete but close...

```
$test="<span>   <span>& nbsp;  </span>  test <span>& nbsp; <span>& nbsp;  </span>  </span> & nbsp;& nbsp; </span>";

$pattern = '#<(\w+)[^>]*>(& nbsp;|\s)*</\1>#im';      
while(preg_match($pattern, $test, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)!= 0)
{$test= preg_replace($pattern,'', $test);}
```

For short $test sentences the function works OK. Problem comes when trying with a long text. Any help will be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Modifying e-satis' answer a bit:

```
function remove_empty_spans($html_replace)
{
$pattern = '/<span[^>]*(?:\/>|>(?:\s|&nbsp;)*<\/span>)/im';
return preg_replace($pattern, '', $html_replace);
}
```

This worked for me.