# ColdFusion Regex for finding empty html tags

Tags: regex, coldfusion, html-parsing, coldfusion-8

Hey all, I'm trying to dynamically strip out some empty html tags. I'm kind of new to Regex, and it seems like the engine for coldfusion isn't as robust/similar to other regex engines (like javascript and as3).

What's the trick for building a regex that ignores spaces in coldfusion 8?  So, if I build this thing out I want it to work on either of the examples below.

```
<p > </p>
<p>         </p>
<P></p>
```

Any help would be really greatful!

Comment: ColdFusion uses the [Apache ORO regex engine](http://jakarta.apache.org/oro/), which is less well featured than some (e.g. Java, .NET, etc), but it still supports most regex features (including some which JavaScript doesn't). You can also dip into Java really easily, which gives you all the features of the java.util.regex classes.

Answer (score 1):

This should work: `<\w+[^>]*(/>|>\s*?</\w+>)`. I think. There are no complex, language specific features (i.e. loohaheads, lookbehinds, etc.)

**Modified from here:** [Regular expression to remove empty <span> tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292516/regular-expression-to-remove-empty-span-tags)

Comment: This is matching stuff like `<p/>` which the OP didn't ask for.
And I don't understand why the lazy quantifiers are used.

A simpler version would be: `<\w+[^>]*>\s*</\w+>` (or `<\w+[^>]*>\s+</\w+>` if `<p></p>` is not desired to match)

A slightly better version still might be: `<\w+.*?>\s+</\w+>` to avoid failing on `<p title="1>2"> </p>`, but if you start down that path you get to worring about stuff like `<p title="<p> </p>"> </p>` and the whole using-a-real-HTML-parser comes into play.

Comment: I was going to suggest using an HTML parser, too. That would prevent things like `<p/>` from getting through. Also, I don't know why I used lazy quantifiers- thanks catching that.

Comment: I believe ColdFusion handles backreferences, so this might work as well: `<(\w+)[^>]*>\s*</\1>`